# Can I get a callback hook for destroy on an object from another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 3.1.3  -  ruby 1.9.3p194

I have 2 objects: Patient & Bill.

When Patient gets destroyed the corresponding Bill gets destroyed. Which is fine; however, these objects are also held remotely on Quickbooks and are updated through my application.

If a Bill is destroyed locally, my application deletes the object in Quickbooks. I do not destroy Patients in Quickbooks because there is most likely associated billing history stored there.

The problem arises when someone destroys a Patient locally, it calls destroy for all associated Bills, which fires the destroy method for Quickbooks Bills.

Is there a way to see if patient.destroy has been called from Bill model?

Comment: before_destroy hook in your models is all I can think of. Perhaps use this in patient to interupt the process?

Comment: How would you add an interupt? Maybe a global variable $patient_destroyed that gets set to true in the Patient Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have something like this

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bills, dependent: :destroy
end 
class Bills < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

You could change this to

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bills, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

`destroy` has callbacks which you are using to remove bills from quickbooks.

`delete` has no callbacks it is just a deletion from the database straight through.

Thus if you destroy a patient it will delete all the `Bills` locally but will not run the callbacks to remove it from quickbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this issue would be to remove the callbacks and to perform the deletion with a separate coordinating object, which would get called from your controller:

```
class PatientAndBillRemoteCleanup
  def initialize(patient)
    @patient = patient
  end

  def delete
    Patient.transaction do 
      # fill out these methods
      # transaction rewinds if you have failures
      delete_patients_bills_in_quickbooks
      delete_patients_bills_locally
      delete_patient_locally
    end
  end 
end
```

The advantages of this approach are:

1. It's much easier to test
2. You can isolate remote deletion to a known
   process (so you don't get unintended effects at the Rails console
3. Any place where this code is used (such as the controller where web
   users trigger deletion) is easy to understand, and someone else
   won't accidentally write patient-deleting code elsewhere that
   unexpectedly manipulates quickbooks

Callbacks are great for situations where you want to do something *every* time (such as set some default data that relies on another attribute), but you have a situation here where sometimes you want the callback behavior, and sometimes you don't. Move it out to a coordinating object and then you can easily control the behavior.